# ActionController::Live Streaming (Rails 4) not properly working with Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to test the new streaming feature. The code below works fine in Chrome, its streaming as it should. However in Firefox 23 I get the dialog window "You have chosen to open" -> "Open with" / "Save file" with that request.

```
def show
  response.headers[ "Content-Type" ] = "text/event-stream"
  3.times { 
    response.stream.write "Hello, browser!\n" 
    sleep 1 }
  response.stream.close
end
```

curl response headers contain:

`Content-Type: text/event-stream`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Firefox 23, but in some browsers [Server-Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) isn't supported.
If it's the case of Firefox 23, try to use [EventSource Polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) that's compatible with older browsers.

For more information about SSEs, [take a look at this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/tkramar/sse-14502043)